# How to create an instanceof AST node using typescript compiler API

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I would like to represent the typescript code "MyObj instanceOf MyClass" with the typescript compiler API.

I try to use the `createBinary` API as follow:

```
ts.createBinary(leftExpression,ts.SyntaxKind.InstanceOfKeyword, rightExpression);
```

How do I create the `rightExpression`?

Answer (score 1):

The left and right expressions are identifiers, so the `createIdentifier` method could be used:

```
const binaryExpression = ts.createBinary(ts.createIdentifier("MyObj"),
    ts.SyntaxKind.InstanceOfKeyword,
    ts.createIdentifier("MyClass"));
```